# how to clear a field in the pop up window in protractor while doing edit on a field

Tags: protractor

Can anyone please help me to clear a field as I am unable to do it in a pop-up window. If I am passing clear as

```
var input = element(by.css(".md-input-infix"));
browser.actions().mouseDown(input).clear().sendKeys("andndn").perform();'
```

Then it is saying that clear is not a function and 2nd i tried to do as:

```
var input = element(by.css(".md-input-infix")).clear();
```

In this case, also I am unable to clear my field.

Answer (score 0):

what is the element of the pop-up. since you are opening a popup it would be a good idea to wait for it to load completely. The sample code bellow show give you some perspective.

```
 var popup = element(locator for popup);
 var input = element(by.css(".md-input-infix"));
 popup.click().then(function(){     
       browser.wait(until.presenceOf(input), 5000, 'Element taking too long to appear in the DOM');
    });
 input.clear().sendKeys("andndn");
```

Comment: ohk i wl try this and let u know whether it is working or not

Comment: but the locator for pop up ,I have provided already in which I am using CSS.So, from where I will get the popup locator.